# Saving Strings like UITextFields, UILabels and UITextView

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring

I´m having problems while saving an extern variable when run through my navigation controller, this is an app where I calculate game points here my code for calculating points:

This is an IBAction for calculating points:

```
- (IBAction)RedTeloBallsTotal:(id)sender {

NSString *firstString = RedTeloBallsOne.text;
NSString *secondString = RedTeloBallsTwo.text;
NSString *thirdString = RedTeloBallsThree.text;
NSString *fourthString = RedTeloBallsFour.text;

NSString *LEGAL = @"0123456789";
NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:LEGAL] invertedSet];
NSString *filteredOne = [[firstString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet] 
                         componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString *filteredTwo = [[secondString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet] 
                         componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString *filteredThree = [[thirdString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet] 
                           componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString *filteredFour = [[fourthString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet] 
                          componentsJoinedByString:@""];

firstString = filteredOne;
secondString = filteredTwo;
thirdString = filteredThree;
fourthString = filteredFour;

//Here we are creating three doubles
double num1;
double num2;
double num3;
double num4;
double output;
//Here we are assigning the values 
num1 = [firstString doubleValue];
num2 = [secondString doubleValue];
num3 = [thirdString doubleValue];
num4 = [fourthString doubleValue];

output = num2 + (num1 * 2) + num4 + (num3 * 25);

//Now we are going to display the output in the label.
RedTeloBallsTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",output];


}
```

Comment: I don't know how to save the variable "output" as an external variable so that whatever the text in the uitextfields is, doesn't get lost

Comment: but doesn't affect the calculations

Answer (score 0):

To save the calculated value, you should create a declared property in your object for it.

For instance, in the header for this object, add this with the other properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) double redTeloBallsTotalOutput;
```

Then, towards the top of your implementation file (.m file) you should see other @synthesize lines, add this one:

```
@synthesize redTeloBallsTotalOutput;
```

In order to set the value in your function above, use:

```
self.redTeloBallsTotalOutput = output;
```

Lastly, to use it in other places within this object, use:

```
self.redTeloBallsTotalOutput
```

Comment: This just saves the output of the calculation to a variable which you can use for whatever you want.  It does not save the text in the text fields, just the output.  If you want to save the text, you need to do the same thing but create NSString properties to store them in.